# Cakephp email with attachment falid

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am trying to send email with attachment in Cakephp 2.6 via Mailgun. It normally working fine unless I add 'attachments($attachments)'. My code is below.

```
$attachments = SITE_URL . '/img/red-hyphen.png';
                            $data = array (
                                    'unique_secret_key' => $unique_secret_key,
                                    'WAYDSiteUrl' => $siteUrl 
                            );
                            $Email = new CakeEmail ( 'mailgun' );

                            $Email->template ( 'forgotpassword', 'default' )
                                    ->emailFormat ( 'html' )
                                    ->viewVars ( $data )
                                    ->subject ( 'Forgot Password' )
                                    ->to ( $chek_exists_record ['Member'] ['email'] )
                                    ->attachments($attachments)
                                    ->send ();
```

I am getting error

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

```
APP\Controller\MembersController.php line 255 → CakeEmail->attachments(string)

'http://localhost/GYB_develop/gyb_source/img/red-hyphen.png'

[internal function] → MembersController->forgotpassword()

CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(MembersController, array)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(MembersController, CakeRequest)
APP\webroot\index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You should try this Cakephp send email with attachment**

email.php file

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'abc@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
```

In your Controller At the top import the cakeemail function

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

After that  your function/Action of your controller

```
          $client_email='sharmavikram054@gmail.com' 
          $Email = new CakeEmail();
          $Email->template('doperesult');
          $Email->viewVars(array( 'unique_secret_key' => $unique_secret_key,'WAYDSiteUrl' => $siteUrl ));
          $Email->emailFormat('html');
          $Email->to($client_email);    
          $Email->from('admin@capeprofileconsultancy.com');
          $Email->attachments(array(
          'red-hyphen.png' => array(
            'file' => WWW_ROOT.'img/red-hyphen.png',
            'mimetype' => 'image/png',
            'contentId' => 'my-unique-id'
                 )
            ));
          $Email->subject('Dummy test');
          if($Email->send('Send Mail')){ 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your Result is successfully send','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect('/');  
          }
```

you can visit the cakephp email link [Cakephp email](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)

Comment: Also tried the above bot no luck. Could you please able to send the full code here?

Comment: tried the above but same. Is it for localhost ?? I mean sending attachment from localhost causes that problem? However I am able to send html or text email from localhost via mailgun

Comment: There is no problem of localhost